# p:dialog show message or reload

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

In a jsf 2.2 primefaces application, I have a link that opens a dialog that has a form. On submission of the form, I want to close the dialog and reload the current page or show an error on the dialog itself.

The managedbean method is a void method that sets the status using RequestContext - addcallbackparam.

As the dialog submission happens using actionlistener and the remainder of the operation happens in javascript, I can’t quite handle this.

I followed the example provided on primefaces website.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/loginDemo.xhtml

Can anyone provide any information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try without using addcallbackparam and javascript..

On validation success, hide the dialog & reload page or on failure, set a warning message as below from managed bean:

```
public void login(ActionEvent event) {    
    if(username != null && username.equals("admin") && password != null && password.equals("admin")) {
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        requestContext.execute("PF('dlg').hide()");
        pageReload();
    } else {
        dialogWarning = "Validation failed";
    }
}

public void pageReload() {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        ec.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).getRequestURI());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //catch and log IO exception here
    }
}
```

In the xhtml dialog set dynamic=true and display the warning message as below and add this id to the update attribute in the Login component.

```
<h:outputLabel id="warnMsgLabel" value="#userLoginView.dialogWarning" />
```